# django url regular expression repeats in URL

Tags: django, url

If I create URL

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',     
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
     url(r'^about/',views.about , name = 'about'),
     url(r'^rango/',views.index, name = 'index'),
)
```

the link `127.0.0.1:8000/about` and `127.0.0.1:8000/about/about/` will direct you to same page isn't it? How do I stop that ? I only want

```
domain-name/about/
```

to be valid and anything (`/about/about/about/...`) should be invalid page.

Answer (score 2):

add $ to the end

> url(r'^about/$',views.about , name = 'about'),

Answer (score 0):

More generally, `about/anything/` will match as well. The `$` indicates the end of a string (or in this case url), just like `^`  indicates the start of it. Checking against `r'^about/'` only checks that the url starts with `about/`, not where it ends.

That is generally the behaviour you want when you include another url config, like `admin/`. In that case, the pattern shouldn't end after `admin/`, but there should be another part that matches a configured url in the included file. But if your pattern is a single view, you generally want the url to end after the end of the pattern, that's when you include the `$`, e.g. `r'^about/$'`.

Comment: But that means i can put anything after domain name followed by /about/ will fetch the same result ? It doesn't look fine , does it?

Comment: @SaurabhKumarKarn If you don't include the `$` - yes. When you include another url configuration, like `admin/`, it's only a partial match though, the `$` is included in the last pattern that matches an actual page.